# Compute: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{2n^4+n^2}\frac{5n^2+1}{n^4+i}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation

The question is to find $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left ( \frac{5n^2+1}{n^4+1}+\frac{5n^2+1}{n^4+2}+\frac{5n^2+1}{n^4+3}+...\frac{5n^2+1}{3n^4+n^2} \right )$

The answer is 5, according to the booklet.

I tried to bring the sum to the form $ \sum \frac{1}{n}f(\frac{k}{n})$ in order to use Rieman sum. Also I tried to apply Cauchy's first theorem on limits. Didn't get me closer to something helpful.

Comment: Do you mean $3n^4+n^2$, or $n^4+n^2$?

Comment: So, what's wrong with $ \sum \frac{1}{n}f(\frac{k}{n})$?

Comment: It seems to be convergent.I use matlab for approximation and its value was growing fast.

Comment: I fixed it, RogerI. It's $3n^4+n^2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a_n=\frac{5n^2+1}{n^4+1}+\frac{5n^2+1}{n^4+2}+\frac{5n^2+1}{n^4+3}+...+\frac{5n^2+1}{n^4+n^2}$, then notice
$$
a_n \geq n^2\cdot \frac{5n^2+1}{n^4+n^2}=\frac{5+\frac{1}{n^2}}{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}
$$
and similarly
$$
a_n \leq n^2 \cdot  \frac{5n^2+1}{n^4+1} = \frac{5+\frac{1}{n^2}}{1+\frac{1}{n^4}}.
$$
Now just use the [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

Comment: I got it wrong in the header - there are $2n^4+n^2$ summonds (as i wrote in the body of the question), not $n^2$

Comment: @rotemaracky That's probably just a typo since your booklet confirms the result should be $5$

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in the question since if we denote the sum by $S$ , then:

$(5n^2+1)\cdot \frac{2n^4}{3n^4+n^2}<S$  and the $LHS$ diverges.